# Underflow in the root of a B-Tree

Tags: tree, overflow, b-tree, underflow

I am trying to implement a 3-4-5-6 Tree.  In the event that a merge causes the root to have only one key (underflow) and its children have a total number of key greater than 5 (so if all merged together, an underflow would happen), what should happen?

Answer (score 0):

Split the children of the root up so that you end up with a "legal" root node and two "legal" children.